# Docker layer caching is re-running a step even its considered as Cached

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, action

I have a Dockerfile, that is built with buildx on GitHub actions with caching enabled. Locally this Dockerfile is running fine with caching capabilities. It's interesting that on Github Actions even though a step is considered as `CACHED`  its running after again and it is broking cache chain.

```
#17 [installer  9/15] COPY .yarn/plugins/ .yarn/plugins
#17 CACHED

#17 [installer  9/15] COPY .yarn/plugins/ .yarn/plugins
#17 sha256:75a8c8bfa7b2e0576a498684c0d01b7e0803ad05d2df1abfbd9d52703b987d98 308B / 308B done
#17 sha256:5fc65d1534010c59114a26a70d6fb661d67482c6204d55b1c2e8877926ff0ccd 439B / 439B 0.0s done
#17 extracting sha256:5fc65d1534010c59114a26a70d6fb661d67482c6204d55b1c2e8877926ff0ccd done
#17 extracting sha256:75a8c8bfa7b2e0576a498684c0d01b7e0803ad05d2df1abfbd9d52703b987d98 done
#17 sha256:71cc0bf883b1cf63b0d9369ae96aca46054ced73992f5a0d92b401417d2aaa28 877.96kB / 877.96kB 0.1s done
#17 extracting sha256:71cc0bf883b1cf63b0d9369ae96aca46054ced73992f5a0d92b401417d2aaa28 0.0s done
#17 sha256:76f856de0dd94689a37a26d13365fe0987d3363a68cce5f355f46dfb9c4c05b4 302.05kB / 302.05kB 0.1s done
#17 extracting sha256:76f856de0dd94689a37a26d13365fe0987d3363a68cce5f355f46dfb9c4c05b4 0.0s done
#17 DONE 0.2s
```

Sent a new commit without changing the file but its causing `CACHED`  layer to re-run again.